# Failed to fetch Product GraphQL Swift

Tags: ios, swift, graphql

Did you find solution for this? I didn't get product detail even using your code Storefront.Product?

```
    @discardableResult
func fetchProduct(id: String, completion: @escaping (Storefront.Product?) -> Void) -> Task {
    let query = ClientQuery.queryForProduct(id: id)
     let task  = self.client.queryGraphWith(query) { (query, error) in
         error.debugPrint()

        if let product = query?.node as? Storefront.Product? {
        completion (product)
        }
        else {
        print("Failed to fetch Product: \(String(describing: error))")
        completion (nil)
            }
            
        }
     task.resume()
     return task
}

    //-
static func queryForProduct (id: String) -> Storefront.QueryRootQuery {
    let id = GraphQL.ID(rawValue: id)
    return Storefront.buildQuery { $0
        .node(id: id) { $0
            .onProduct() { $0
                .id()
                .title()
                .onlineStoreUrl()
            }
        }
    }
}//end of final class
```

**And here I am calling my function**

```
        let id = GraphQL.ID(rawValue: "gid://shopify/Product/5375310233754")

    Client.shared.fetchProduct(id: id.rawValue) {
         Product1 in
        guard let Product1 = Product1 else {

              print("Failed to fetch Product")
              return
        }
```

I am getting this error.
**Graph.QueryError: invalidQuery(reasons: [MobileBuySDK.Graph.QueryError.Reason(message: "Invalid global id `gid://shopify/Product/5375317082266`", line: nil, column: nil)])
Failed to fetch Product**

Comment: are you sure your product id is right?

Comment: @RuchiMakadia Yes product id is right

Answer (score 0):

try like this for me it's working code

```
 func queryForProducts(in collection: Storefront.CollectionEdge?, limit: Int, after cursor: String? = nil) -> Storefront.QueryRootQuery {
    let id = collection?.node.id.rawValue //?? UserDefaultsConfig.our_shop_id
    return Storefront.buildQuery { $0
        Collection { $0
            .products(first: Int32(limit), after: cursor) { $0
                .fragmentForStandardProduct()
                }
                .node(id: GraphQL.ID(rawValue: id)) { $0
            .on
            }
        }
    }
}


extension Storefront.ProductConnectionQuery {
    
    @discardableResult
    func fragmentForStandardProduct() -> Storefront.ProductConnectionQuery { return self
        .pageInfo { $0
            .hasNextPage()
        }
        .edges { $0
            .cursor()
            .node { $0
                .id()
                .title()
                .tags()
                .productType()
                .descriptionHtml()
                .createdAt()
                .priceRange { $0
                    .maxVariantPrice { $0
                    .amount()
                }
                .minVariantPrice{ $0
                    .amount()
                    }
                }
                /*.metafields{ $0
                    .edges { $0
                        .node { $0
                            .id()
                            .key()
                        }
                    }
                }*/
                .availableForSale()
                .variants(first: 10) { $0
                    .fragmentForVarient()
                    
                }
                .images(first: 10){ $0
                    .edges { $0
                        .node{ $0
                            .id()
                            .originalSrc()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



  func query_graph(root_query: Storefront.QueryRootQuery ,completion:@escaping (_ result: Storefront.QueryRoot?, _ error: Graph.QueryError?) -> Void){
            let task = client.queryGraphWith(root_query) { response, error in
                if let response = response {
                    completion(response, nil)
                } else {
                    completion(nil, error)
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
```

make query

```
let query = Model.shared.queryForProducts(in: self.obj_catagory, limit: 10, after: self.productsCursor)
```

call query function

```
 query_graph(root_query: query) { (response, error) in
        //Model.shared.hideActivityIndicator(controller: self)
        if error != nil {
           //error
        }
        else {
            let collection = response?.node as? Storefront.Collection
            print(collection)
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but then how will I call for a particular id using these functions? Can you give me example with particular id.?

Comment: hi ruchi, need some help